# Admin Form Custom Multiple select box

Tags: python, django

I have completed my models and I am trying to customise the admin model for a particular model.

Here is my admin.py

```
from project.base.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class StaffModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = StaffModule

class StaffModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StaffModuleForm
    class Meta:
        pass

Modules = [UserProfile, Student, Module, StaffModule, Exercise, Result]
admin.site.register(Modules)
```

and here is the model in question

```
class StaffModule(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module) # Field name made lowercase.
    department = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Here is the error I am currently unable to pass:

```
AttributeError at /admin/base/staffmodule/2/
type object 'StaffModuleAdmin' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Here is the trace: http://pastebin.com/tCJ9Q978

I would really appreciate some help, as I believe I am following the django admin docs and i am not quite sure what the issue is.

Thanks.

Comment: Also your question is a bit vague, it is always better to ask a question and explain what you are trying to do (in this example how to customize the admin page) and what you have tried so far with traces if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this:

```
class StaffModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StaffModuleForm
    class Meta:
        pass
```

Inner `Class Meta` should not be defined for the `admin.ModelAdmin` class.